# Condition in switch's case is ignored

Tags: javascript, if-statement, switch-statement

I'm trying to use a switch statement as follow. But even if status is 301, the case `case (status > 200 && status < 400)` is ignored and the result is the "default" case.
What am I doing wrong? Is it not possibile to use conditions in case statements?

```js
status = 301;
switch (status) {
  case 0:
  case 200:
    console.log('200');
    break;
  case (status > 200 && status < 400):
    console.log('200-400');
    break;
  case 404:
    console.log('404');
    break;
  default:
    console.log('Si è verificato un errore irreversibile.');
}
```

At the end I solved with a simple if, but I would like to know why this doesn't work.

Comment: why would `status > 200 && status < 400` (which is either `true` or `false`) be equal to `status` (which is probably a number)? - `switch (x)` `case y` is like `if (x === y)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not how `switch`/`case` works in JavaScript; you can only match values, not conditions. What happens here is that `status > 200 && status < 400` evaluates to `true`, and `true` is obviously not the same as `301`.

Indeed a simple `if`/`else if`/.../`else` chain is the usual solution here.

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved by following:

```js
const status = 301;
switch (true) {
  case status === 0:
  case status === 200:
    console.log('200');
    break;
  case (status > 200 && status < 400):
    console.log('200-400');
    break;
  case status === 404:
    console.log('404');
    break;
  default:
    console.log('Si è verificato un errore irreversibile.');
}
```

But I agree with @Thomas's suggestion, we should prefer using the `if`/`else` chain for these kind of problems.